# Adding fade transition between animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

My problem looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover!important;
  background-size: cover!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  animation: image 8s linear 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);
}
@keyframes image {
  20% {
    background-position: 25% center;
  }
  40% {
    background-position: 50% center;
  }
  60% {
    background-position: 75% center;
  }
  80% {
    background-position: 100% center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image" style="background:url(http://i.imgur.com/GX23d5Y.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

I have a long image that consists of say 5 images stitched together, and I'm animating its `background-position` in a similar manner.

Currently the transition is happening, but in steps, so each image 'blinks'.

I was wondering if it's possible to have some kind of fade in/out along with the `background-position` change. I tried inserting

```
0% { opacity:1; }
20% { background-position: 25% center; opacity:0; }
21% { opacity:1; }
```

Into my animation, but I couldn't get a good fade in/out effect.

Any advice on how to do it (without inserting multiple images like [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)) is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a `animation: fadein 2s;`

Comment: Can you give a sample code to show what you mean by *5 images stitched together* please? It is fine even if the images are completely unrelated. Just a sample should be fine.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL2447f3/)?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan: Nice one except that I think it can't be done with a single animation because OP is looking for a step increase on the image (that is, more like a jump/blink instead of a gradual progress). Combining opacity change with the image step animation would ruin that.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan I've tried this and that's not quite good, because you kinda loose the second slide in the opacity change.

Comment: @dingo_d, but slide effect must be visible right?

Comment: I've edited my snippet to show what I have, I'll look your answer now Harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you need two animations where one fades the images in & out in a linear manner whereas the other shifts the background position in a step-wise manner.

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/GX23d5Y.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: image 8s steps(1) 1s infinite, fadein 8s linear 1s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes image {
  20% {background-position: 25% center;}
  40% {background-position: 50% center;}
  60% {background-position: 75% center;}
  80% {background-position: 100% center;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
  10%  {opacity: 1;}
  20%  {opacity: 0;}
  30%  {opacity: 1;}
  40%  {opacity: 0;}
  50%  {opacity: 1;}
  60%  {opacity: 0;}
  70%  {opacity: 1;}
  80%  {opacity: 0;}
  90%  {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

As you can see, the `image` animation does exactly what you seem to be having already (that is, shift the `background-position`). The second animation does the following:

- **Between 0% and 10%**, it changes `opacity` in a linear manner from **0** to **1**. This makes it look as though the first part of the image is fading in on load.
- **At 20%** (exactly the same time when the position is shifted to the second image), `opacity` again becomes **0**. This hides the image temporarily.
- Then after a short while **at 30%** we animate the `opacity` back again to **1** which gives the fade in appearance to the second part of the image.
- Similar pattern is followed for the 3rd, 4th and 5th parts of the image also. That is for the first **10%**, the image fades in and for the next **10%** it fades out.
- Finally **at 100%**, the `opacity` becomes **0** again because we want the first part of the image to fade-in during the next cycle.

  ```css
  .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/GX23d5Y.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: image 8s steps(1) 1s infinite, fadein 8s linear 1s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  @keyframes image {
    20% {background-position: 25% center;}
    40% {background-position: 50% center;}
    60% {background-position: 75% center;}
    80% {background-position: 100% center;}
  }
  @keyframes fadein {
    10%  {opacity: 1;}
    20%  {opacity: 0;}
    30%  {opacity: 1;}
    40%  {opacity: 0;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    60%  {opacity: 0;}
    70%  {opacity: 1;}
    80%  {opacity: 0;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>

  </div>
  ```
- The keyframe breakup used in the snippet results in a continuous fade in and out of image parts (that is, the image stays at `opacity: 1` only for a very short amount of time). If you need to give a break, just modify the frames accordingly. A sample is available in the below snippet:

  ```css
  .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/GX23d5Y.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: image 16s steps(1) 1s infinite, fadein 16s linear 1s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  @keyframes image {
    20% {background-position: 25% center;}
    40% {background-position: 50% center;}
    60% {background-position: 75% center;}
    80% {background-position: 100% center;}
  }
  @keyframes fadein {
    5%  {opacity: 1;}
    15%  {opacity: 1;}
    20%  {opacity: 0;}
    25%  {opacity: 1;}
    35%  {opacity: 1;}
    40%  {opacity: 0;}
    45%  {opacity: 1;}
    55%  {opacity: 1;}
    60%  {opacity: 0;}
    65%  {opacity: 1;}
    75%  {opacity: 1;}
    80%  {opacity: 0;}
    85%  {opacity: 1;}
    95%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>

  </div>
  ```

Comment: Ok I'll try this on my example, but I'm pretty sure this looks like what I need :)

Comment: @dingo_d: That's nice. I have added an extra snippet which uses the image from question.

Comment: Yeap this does it! I've been playing in the fiddle to get it to work with 5, but you beat me to it :D Thanks ^^